# What is the name of this plant with small, 5-leaved divided pink blooms?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I found this in a forest in Karlsruhe (Germany).

The blooms are pink and have 5 leaves. Each leave is divided into two parts. It is pink and has a diameter of about 1-2cm.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a [Red Campion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silene_dioica), which is native to northern and central Europe.

[image]

It would be nice to see a close-up of the calyx (which is usually striped) and the leaves to be sure; it may be a cross between a White and Red Campion.

There are many members of the genus, and many look alike. Your close-up is of a male flower (anthers only). The plants are male or female.

Answer (score 2):

Looks kind of like a species in the genus *Silene*. Interesting group, I believe some species in this group are dioecious and have sex chromosomes.